# Можно ли dd убить флешку физически?

Tags: linux, usb, dd

Можно ли **dd** "убить" флешку физически?

После нескольких (около 5, от силы 10) попыток создать загрузочную флешку dd заметил, что скорость копирования достигла до 40 Мб/с. Я не обратил внимания на это. Образ начал грузиться но потом ошибка. Пробовал затереть флешку

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M
```

Так тут скорость вообще на уровне 1 Гб/сек и копируется за пару сек (флешка на 4 Гб)
fdisk, gparted её видит. Повторил запись образа — закидывается (на сей раз около 15 Мб/сек), но в процессе загрузки с образа снова сбой.

Если важно, то пробую загрузиться с флешки на маке. [Проверка макбука на сбойные сектора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828477/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: Скорость врёт. После записи нужно выполнить `sync`, который зависнет на несколько (десятков) минут, пока запись на флешку будет завершаться :)

Comment: физически убить - нет, нельзя. Только духовно можно убить

Comment: sync завершается за несколько секунд. Скорость, может и врёт, но образ 1,5 Гб не может записаться на флешку за 38 сек.

Comment: @misdeed , у меня друг жаловался как раз на физическое убиение, жаль он повыкидывал те флешки — нет материала для глубокого исследования.

Comment: Ну давайте, могу помочь. Самому интересно. Что нужно делать?
Тем более есть ещё один "странный" экземпляр — старый Кингстон на 4 Гб. Под линуксом  с помощью Gparted  она была разбита на два раздела 3 и 1 Гб. Позже её переформатировали под виндой. И "отделённая" часть пропала — стала флешка на 3 Гб.  Тот же Gparted видит её теперь как 3Гб. Затирал полностью dd нулями, безрезультатно.